# 2-D Gaussian Low Pass Filter using imgaussfilt in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I want to design a 2-D Gaussian low-pass filter using **imgaussfilt** in MATLAB so that **95%** of its mass lies within a predefined **radius**. If **sigma** (standard deviation) is set to **0.5** (default), how should I calculate **'FilterSize'** (Size of the Gaussian filter)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, no, no...  The standard deviation controls the spread of the filter, so a small value of sigma means that the filter is very narrow, and a large value means that it is spread widely.  To find out how much of its mass lies within a given radius, you need to do some mathematics...  It turns out that a 2D Gaussian distribution is related to a [Rayleigh distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_distribution#Related_distributions), so what you really need is the 95% point of a standardized Rayleigh distribution, then you can scale sigma accordingly.

Using the equations on the Wikipedia page for the Rayleigh CDF, it is easy to find that for a sigma value of 1 (the normalised distribution), the 95% point is at a radius of 2.45.  So, you should scale sigma to alter the distribution width accordingly.

The filter size depends on how much of the filter you want to use.  If you make this too small, and you truncate the filter too much, then it will not be a good approximation to a Gaussian.  Too large, on the other hand, and it will be pointless.  What you can do is use the same equation to find the radius of the point where you are no longer interested in the result (e.g. the 99%, or you could even use the 95% if you really wanted, but remember that you are missing 5% of the data that would otherwise make it through the filter).